# Cell change background colour with clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table and I have one 1 cell that I can't fix. What I want is to have a background colour blue and when I click the

```
<p> 2 click me </p>
```

I want to make this background cell green. I take only the code for this specific cell, what I have done and it doesn't work as I want..

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("colour").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
}
                
var x = document.getElementById('colour');

if (x.style.backgroundColor === 'green') {
  x.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
} else {
  x.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}
```

```css
#click{
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 1rem;
  width : 50%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<tr>  
  <td id="click">
    <div id="colour" onclick="myFunction()">
      <p>2 click me<p>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Replace `#` with `.` and add class via your js

Comment: ok about the replace the # and . , what class you mean? You mean to put a button ,id, or div?

Comment: Your css `<style>` part. Replace `#` which means one of a kind, a unique id. Where `.` period prepend is a class definition. Then in your `myFunction()` add the class.

Comment: Code is flawed in other areas, but these simple changes you can learn.

Comment: @GetSet moment  I am the way to do it

Comment: @GetSet it doesnt change my cell background colour

Comment: Your if-statement is only ever run once, that is, when the page is loaded. Place it inside your `myFunction()` since all else from your code actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want?  I think you just need to assign a variable to the element colour and then use it to make your changes

```js
function myFunction() {
  const x = document.getElementById("colour");
  const y = document.getElementById("click");
  x.innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";

if (y.style.backgroundColor === 'green') {
    y.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  } else {
    y.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  }
}
```

```css
#click {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td id = "click">
    <div id="colour" onclick="myFunction()">
      <p>2 click me</p>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You actually reformatted the code to work. The original had the problem of the if-statement not being inside the function-body. You should mention that in your answer.

Comment: kind a way...I want td to be the green(when I click it) .When I click the p  to become the whole cell  green not only the word..

Comment: @amanon I updated my code, you just need another variable set to your td

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     function myFunction() {
>           document.getElementById("colour").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
>         }
>         
>         var x = document.getElementById('colour');
>             if (x.style.backgroundColor === 'green') {
>                 x.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
>             } else {
>                 x.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
>             }
> ```

```
            **</script>**
```

You forgot to close with the script tag I think, right?

Because for me closing with the  tag it works

Answer (score 1):

> #click{
>     background-color:blue;
>     padding:1rem;
>     width : 50%;
>     height:50px;
>     margin:auto;
>     
>     }
>
> ```
> <body>
> <tr>  
> <td  id="click" > <div id="colour" onclick="myFunction()"><p>2 click me<p></div></td>
>     </tr>
> </body>
>
>
>
>
>
>  <script type="text/javascript">
>
> var x = document.getElementById('colour');
>
>     function myFunction() {
>           document.getElementById("colour").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
>         }
>         
>         x.addEventListener('click', function()
>         {
>            if (x.style.backgroundColor === 'green') {
>                 x.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
>             } else {
>                 x.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
>             }
>             });
>             
>             </script>
> ```

With this it should work!